# Joomla template - customize for different dates

Tags: templates, joomla

I don't know if this is at all possible, but I believe it is.  Can you customize your joomla template to say for example on 14 February every year display a different logo?  If yes, where do I start?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without modifying the PHP code of the template. In your example, I would modify:

```
<h1 id="name-text" class="art-logo-name"></h1>
```

to

```
<h1 id="name-text" class="art-logo-name date_<?php echo date('m_d'); ?>"></h1>
```

Then you can add to your CSS file:

```
.art-logo-name { background: url('normal') no-repeat; }
.art-logo-name.date_02_14 { background-image: url('special.png'); }
```

Comment: Thank you, I assume I must start in the index.php?  I've found this code can it be this?

Comment: <div class="art-logo">
 <?php if ($logoType == 'image'): ?>
        <h1 id="name-text" class="art-logo-name"><a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/images/logo.gif" title="<?php echo $mainframe->getCfg('sitename') ;?>" border="0"></a></h1>
 <?php else: ?>
  <h1 id="name-text" class="art-logo-name">
   <a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/"><?php echo $logoText; ?></a>
  </h1>
  <p class="site-slogan"><?php echo $sloganText;?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
    
</div>

Comment: I've changed my code to reflect your template. But still, it depends on the parameter of the template: the logo should not be included as image. The reason why I did it as CSS: in this way, you can change the code of the template once, then add images in the CSS part only. Of course you could also hard-code it into the index.php : `if (date('m.d.') == '02.14.') { ... } else { ... }`